# Which browser performs better with Asp.Net development Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, google-chrome

It is about the efficiency, which chrome being light weight, fine for general web browsing.

I am thinking to use it as default browser when working on Web Applications. There are some limitation though which I know like, Could not use chrome when worked over an Rss Feed generator module, as chrome was not supporting the generated output.

Which browser will make it a good combination with VS 2008, C#, Asp.Net dev Server for developing Asp.Net Web Applications.

(Not concerned about the User Interface, Layouts, presentation CSS or same. It is about checking **business logic** implementation or **serve rside** testing, when we check behaviour not presentation. It is when we have to kick debugger into action every other minute to see how application / module / class / statement, whatever is behaving like, but not how application looks )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox + Firebug is truly a deadly combo.

As for the performance problems with ASP development server, try the following:

- go to about:config (write it into the address bar)
- change the value of the **network.dns.disableIPv6** property to **true**

Comment: +1: a very good fix. Have you got any good information resource link about "network.dns.disableIPv6" ? Thanks

Comment: If I remember correctly, I found the fix here: http://codepoetry.wordpress.com/2007/03/27/firefox-very-slow-on-localhost-connections-on-vista/

Answer (score 1):

A web developer with only one browser is like a cook with only one knife. You could always try everything you do as a web application on many different browsers. Some things may not work or may not look like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Firefox and Firebug when debugging client-side javascript issues, and I sometimes use Firefox to ensure the app works in that browser too (we require FireFox and IE support) so on one level you will need multiple browsers to validate the web site works in all of them to reach a wider audience.

I like to use IE so I can use the in-built debugging capabilities (inside VS), which you don't get with the other browsers.  I like to use Firefox for the client-side JS errors that I may encounter.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with Firefox and the visual studio dev server.
It works fine, but it's slow for no apparent reason.

When I'm more concerned with server-side debugging, I tend to use IE simply because it loads the pages faster.
Once you're working on client-side testing/debugging though, you should definitely be working with a variety of browsers. I start with Firefox just because I love the Firebug addon more than I probably should!

Comment: That is what the problem I had, Firebox was always taking 20 seconds for even a WebApplication project just created with a single default page.